# SQL Joining 2 Tables

Tags: sql

I would like to merge two tables into one and also add a counter next to that. What i have now is

```
SELECT [CUCY_DATA].*, [DIM].[Col1], [DIM].[Col2], 
  (SELECT COUNT([Cut Counter]) FROM [MSD] 
   WHERE [CUCY_DATA].[Cut Counter] = [MSD].[Cut Counter]
   ) AS [Nr Of Errors] 
FROM [CUCY_DATA] FULL JOIN [DIM] 
    ON [CUCY_DATA].[Cut Counter] = [DIM].[Cut Counter]
```

This way the data is inserted but where the values don't match nulls are inserted. I want for instance this

Table CUCY_DATA

```
|_Cut Counter_|_Data1_|_Data2_|
|      1      |   12  |   24  |
|      2      |   13  |   26  |
|      3      |   10  |   20  |
|      4      |   11  |   22  |
```

Table DIM

```
|_Cut Counter_|_Col1_|_Col2_|
|      1      |   25  |   40  |
|      3      |   50  |   45  |
```

And they need to be merged into:

```
|_Cut Counter_|_Data1_|_Data2_|_Col1_|_Col2_|
|      1      |   12  |   24  |  25  |  40  |
|      2      |   13  |   26  |  25  |  40  |
|      3      |   10  |   20  |  50  |  45  |
|      4      |   11  |   22  |  50  |  45  |
```

SO THIS IS WRONG:

```
|_Cut Counter_|_Data1_|_Data2_|_Col1__|_Col2__|
|      1      |   12  |   24  |  25   |   40  |
|      2      |   13  |   26  |  NULL |  NULL |
|      3      |   10  |   20  |  50   |   45  |
|      4      |   11  |   22  |  NULL |  NULL |
```

Kind regards, Bob

Answer (score 0):

How are you getting the col1 and col2 values where there is no corresponding row in your DIM table?  (Rows 2 and 4).  Your "wrong" result is exactly correct, that's what the outer join does.